# RequireJS baseUrl and multiple optimized files

Tags: requirejs, requirejs-optimizer

I've separated out my 3rd party libraries from my app code and grouped them all together into a `vendor.js` file for requirejs to pull in. In my `build.js` file, I'm using the `modules` syntax to optimize my main application, excluding the vendor scripts, and to optimize the `vendor.js` file. The only issue I'm having is when my compiled `main` module requests `vendor`, it's getting the `baseUrl` from the config file and so doesn't load the optimized `vendor.js` file. My `build.js` file looks like this:

```
({
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "build",
    mainConfigFile: "js/main.js",
    removeCombined: true,
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    skipDirOptimize: true,
    inlineText: true,
    useStrict: true,
    wrap: true,
    keepBuildDir: false,
    optimize: "uglify2",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "vendor"
        },
        {
            name: "main",
            exclude: ["vendor"]
        }
    ]
})
```

And my `main.js` file looks like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min',
        bootstrap: 'vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
        handlebars: 'vendor/handlebars/handlebars-v2.0.0',
        backbone: 'vendor/backbone/backbone-min',
        underscore: 'vendor/lodash/lodash.underscore',
        marionette: 'vendor/marionette/backbone.marionette.min',
        models: 'common/models',
        collections: 'common/collections'
    }
});

define(['module', 'vendor'], function(module) {
    var configPath = "config/config." + module.config().env;
    require([configPath, 'app', 'jquery'], function(config, Application, $) {
        $(function() {
            // Kick off the app
            Application.start(config);
        });
    });
});
```

All development is done in the `js` folder, and my `build.js` file is outside that folder. The optimized files end up in `build`, a sibling to `js`, but when I include my main file like this:

```
<script data-main="build/main" src="js/vendor/require/require.max.js"></script>
```

It ends up loading `js/vendor.js` for that `define()` call. What am I missing here? How can I tell the optimized `main` file to load `build/vendor.js` instead, yet allow the unoptimized version to still load `js/vendor.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. It was simple, really, just a case of too much configuration. When you load your script using `data-main`, the baseUrl is set relative to that file. So, if I specified `js/main`, the `baseUrl` would be `js`. But, since I explicitly specified `baseUrl` in the config block of `main.js`, that gets overridden, both in development and production. By removing `baseUrl: "js"` from `main.js`, everything works as expected. The development build loads everything relative to `js` and the production build loads everything (`vendor.js`) relative to `build` when I change `data-main` to `build/main`. Hope this helps somebody else someday.

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min',
        ...
    }
});

// 'vendor' is loaded relative to whatever directory main.js is in
define(['module', 'vendor'], function(module) {
    ...
});
```